# com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, nosuchmethoderror

I have been trying to use *JasperReports* to generate reports but getting this error:

```
WARNING: #{order_approval.print}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V
javax.faces.FacesException: #{order_approval.print}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at mtr.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:528)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:383)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:122)
    at to_pages.order_approval.print(order_approval.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 30 more
```

and here is the code in the bean .

```
try {
        String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRealPath("reports");
        System.err.println(reportPath + "\\report1.jrxml");

        JasperCompileManager
                .compileReportToFile(
                        "C:\\reports\\report1.jrxml",
                        "C:\\reports\\report1.jasper");
        System.err.println(reportPath);
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
                orders);
        System.err.println(reportPath);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager
                .fillReport(
                        "C:\\Projects\\reports\\report1.jasper",
                        new HashMap<String, Object>(),
                        beanCollectionDataSource);
        System.err.println("Check");
        JasperExportManager
                .exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
                        "C:\\Projects\\reports\\report1.pdf");
        System.err.println("Check");
    } catch (JRException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

I am using jasperreports 4.1.3 .jar and itextpdf 5.4.5 .jar

Comment: Try to replace itext jar with 2.1.5 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V
```

is telling you that in the class `com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter` you are using no `setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V` method exist. Usually this happens when not required jar version is used.

Find the appropriate version of the jar containing the method `setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V` in the class `com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter`: I guess `itext-2.1.7.jar`.